# How to get courses through transactions table Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I want to get all users with courses through transaction table.

Here is my db structure

**course**

```
id | name | description | price
```

**transactions**

```
id | course_id | user_id | name | description | expires
```

**users**

```
id | username | email
```

http://laravel.io/bin/da08n

I have tried with joins but it returns the same user multiple times.

```
DB::table('transactions')->join('users', 'transactions.user_id', '=', 'users.id')->join('courses', 'transactions.course_id', '=', 'courses.id')->distinct()->get();
```

How can I achieve this with Eloquent or in an other way?

Comment: You should establish relationship between tables

Comment: How can I do it because Im learning about laravel(newbie)

Comment: I'm writing the answer, wait

Comment: @MostafaTalebi Im waiting for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well.

you have a table called transactions, and a table of courses. Now, each transaction is related to a course.
Pay Attention: You have one record in one table which is related to another one record in another table, this is called one-to-one relationship.

In laravel, you achieve this by using Model's relationship.

You have one model called 'Transaction', and another model which is called 'Courses".

You get, for example one record from courses table by using `Cources::find($myId)`.

Now, if you want to get a record of transactions by relating it to courses table., you should do this (in Laravel):

In your translation model define a method called course:

```
public function course ()
{
   $this->hasOne("course"); // course is the name of another model which should be related
}
```

And then you use it like this:

```
$result = Transaction::find($myCourseId)->course();
```

Though for your case, you want to get many records through matching one record of a table to the another record of another table. Well:

In Transaction model add the following method:

```
public function Users()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('User', 'Course');
    }
```

With the above method you should be able to get the Users through Course method based on transactions.

More on that, please visit:

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships

Comment: But like I said in my quetion: `I want to get all users with courses through transaction table.` You show me how to get transaction belongs to course.

Comment: When I use hasManyThrough I got `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'clare_courses.transaction_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `clare_users`.*, `clare_courses`.`transaction_id` from `clare_users` inner join `clare_courses` on `clare_courses`.`id` = `clare_users`.`course_id` where `clare_courses`.`transaction_id` in (1, 3, 4, 5))`

Comment: Read Laravel's documentation, it seems you need to change the default foreign keys and primary keys.